# How to prevent the application stop, when user looses focus on browser tab

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Why the flash application pauses, when the user switch tabs in the browser?, how to prevent that?, I need to make it play continuosly

**updated:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Module 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="init();"
    xmlns:MyComp="components.*">


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import library.TicketCard;
            import library.UtilFunctions;

            [Embed(source="../images/ball1.png")] 
            private var red:Class;
            [Embed(source="../images/ball2.png")] 
            private var orange:Class;
            [Embed(source="../images/ball3.png")] 
            private var blue:Class;
            [Embed(source="../images/ball4.png")] 
            private var green:Class;
            [Embed(source="../images/ball5.png")] 
            private var purple:Class;

            private var numTimer:Timer;
            private var step:int;
            public var currentRand:Number;
            public var randNumbers:Array;
            public var vNum:Array;
            public var speedAnim:Number;
            [Bindable]
            public var countNum:int = 0;
            public var ticketsBought:*;

            private function init():void {

                vNum = new Array();
                step = 1;
                ticketsBought = parentApplication.m_ticket.child.ticketsBought;
                speedAnim = 1000;
                generateNumbers();
                randNumbers = new Array();
                for(var i:int = 0; i < 90; i++)
                {
                    randNumbers.push((i + 1));

                }
                numTimer = new Timer(1000, 180);
                numTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
                numTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTickComplete);
                initialPosition();
                numTimer.start();
            }

            private function initialPosition():void {

                bigBall.width = 4;
                bigBall.height = 4;
                bigBall.horizontalCenter = -92;
                bigBallLabel.horizontalCenter = bigBall.horizontalCenter;
                bigBallLabel.setStyle('fontSize', 1);

            }

            private function onTickComplete(e:TimerEvent):void {

                parentApplication.showMessage('end game!');

            }

            private function onTick(e:TimerEvent):void {

                if(step == 1)
                {
                    if(countNum < 90)
                    {
                        countNum++;
                    }
                    var rand:Number = UtilFunctions.randomRange(randNumbers.length - 1, 0);
                    currentRand = randNumbers[rand];
                    for(var i:int = 0; i < ticketsBought.length; i++)
                    {

                        var ticket:* = ticketsBought[i];
                        var numbers:Array = ticket.ticketNumbers;
                        for(var j:int = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
                        {

                            if(numbers[j].text == currentRand)
                            {
                                var num:* = numbers[j];
                                num.setStyle('backgroundColor', '#552c68');
                                num.setStyle('color', '#FFFFFF');
                                ticket.checkedNumbers++;
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    randNumbers.splice(rand, 1);
                    var n:* = vNum[rand];
                    n.alpha = 1;
                    vNum.splice(rand, 1);
                    bigBallLabel.text = currentRand.toString();
                    startIncreaseAnim();
                }
                else
                if(step == 2)
                {
                    startReduceAnim();
                }
                numTimer.stop();

            }

            private function generateNumbers():void {

                for(var i:int = 0; i < 90; i++)
                {
                    var m:MyImg = new MyImg();
                    var c:Canvas = new Canvas();
                    var l:Label = new Label();
                    l.text = (i + 1).toString();
                    l.horizontalCenter = 0;
                    l.verticalCenter = 0;
                    c.width = 25;
                    c.height = 25;
                    c.alpha = 0.3;
                    vNum.push(c);
                    m.horizontalCenter = 0;
                    m.verticalCenter = 0;

                    if(i >= 0 && i < 18)
                    {
                        m.source = red;
                    }
                    else if(i >= 18 && i < 36)
                    {
                        m.source = orange;

                    }
                    else if(i >= 36 && i < 54)
                    {

                        m.source = blue;
                    }
                    else if(i >= 54 && i < 72)
                    {
                        m.source = green;
                    }
                    else if(i >= 72 && i < 90)
                    {
                        m.source = purple;
                    }
                    c.addChild(m);
                    c.addChild(l);
                    numbersBlock.addChild(c);
                }
            }

            public function startIncreaseAnim():void {

                stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, increaseAnim);

            }

            public function startReduceAnim():void {

                stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, reduceAnim);

            }

            public function endIncreaseAnim():void {

                stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, increaseAnim);

            }

            public function endReduceAnim():void {

                stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, reduceAnim);

            }

            public function increaseAnim(e:Event):void {

                bigBall.width += 4;
                bigBall.height += 4;
                bigBall.horizontalCenter += 4;
                bigBallLabel.horizontalCenter = bigBall.horizontalCenter;
                bigBallLabel.setStyle('fontSize', bigBallLabel.getStyle('fontSize') + 1);
                if(bigBall.horizontalCenter >= 0)
                {
                    step = 2;
                    endIncreaseAnim();
                    numTimer.start();
                }

            }

            public function reduceAnim(e:Event):void {

                bigBall.width -= 4;
                bigBall.height -= 4;
                bigBall.horizontalCenter += 4;
                bigBallLabel.horizontalCenter = bigBall.horizontalCenter;
                bigBallLabel.setStyle('fontSize', bigBallLabel.getStyle('fontSize') - 1);
                if(bigBall.horizontalCenter >= 90)
                {
                    step = 1;
                    initialPosition();
                    endReduceAnim();
                    numTimer.start();
                }

            }
            ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";


    </fx:Style>

    <mx:VBox height="727" width="176" styleName="leftBar" verticalGap="4">
        <mx:Box verticalGap="12">
            <mx:Box width="176" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
                <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100" id="bigBallWrapper" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
                    <MyComp:MyImg id="bigBall" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" source="@Embed(source='../images/ball1-1.png')"/>
                    <s:Label color="#000000" id="bigBallLabel" fontSize="24" text="45" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" />
                </mx:Canvas>
                <mx:Canvas width="100%">
                    <s:Label text="ball # {countNum}" fontSize="18" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" />
                </mx:Canvas>
            </mx:Box>
            <MyComp:MyImg id="bingoLeft" source="@Embed(source='../images/bingoLeft.png')"/>
        </mx:Box>
        <mx:Tile fontSize="12" fontFamily="bor" color="black" direction="vertical" horizontalGap="9" height="100%" width="100%" paddingLeft="8" paddingRight="8" id="numbersBlock" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">

        </mx:Tile>
    </mx:VBox>
</s:Module>
```

a little complicated code :), but the timer executes at first time, then it stops, after eachg animation it starts, I use it as a setTimeout(in js)

Comment: Umm, perhaps it's because you don't want Flash eating up your CPU when it's not visible. With that said, I've never seen this as a problem with any of the apps I've worked on or used. For example, look at any site that plays video with Flash, like YouTube. The video does not stop when I switch tabs (based on the fact that I still hear the audio portion of the video). But at the same time, I wouldn't be surprised if Flash Player was optimized to not worry about updating the screen when the Flash Player wasn't visible.

Comment: but what if my application is client-server, and the server is sending some data to the client, but the client is paused, and I am waiting something, but i've switched tabs for a while...

Comment: I still don't think that's an issue. I sort of took your word for it and said that it seems like a fair optimization for Flash Player to make (not bothering to update screen when Flash app isn't even visible). But in reality, I've never had this problem ... can you point to a site on the internet that has this issue or suggest some steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: What i'am using in my app is a Timer and animations enterframe, looks like the Timer or the enterframe animation stops, and the actionsDepends of the enterFrame handler && timer, thats the problem

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. I'd love to see an example of your code that exhibits this problem. There may be a way to work around the issue... what I suspect is that when Flash is not visible code that uses the "enterFrame" event is probably not executed as often or at all but I am just guessing. If you have a simple example of the problem, please share... this is an interesting problem.

Comment: thats all my module, i need to make a pause of 1 second after each animation thats why i'am using timer, and my actions are based on the animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some observations I've made based on a simple app I've created that:

- has a button to start/stop a `Timer` w/a specified interval
- has a button to add/remove an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` handler
- has a button to add/remove a `FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE` handler
- optionally lets you draw (using the `graphics` property) on each frame
- optionally tries to move a Flex object (a `<s:Rect />`) on each frame

Interesting observations in bold face, code at the bottom.

**Test #1**

When the Flash app's browser tab is in the "foreground", these `Timer` and "enterFrame" event work as expected. The `Timer` fires at the specified interval, and `Event.ENTER_FRAME` is dispatched as quickly as possible (every 30-50 milliseconds on my machine).

**When the Flash app's browser tab is in the "background", `Event.ENTER_FRAME` is dispatched about every 500 milliseconds. If you set the interval of the `Timer` to lower than 500 milliseconds, the `Timer` will also only fire about every 500 milliseconds.**

So as we guessed, when Flash Player knows it's not visible, it tries to use less CPU by firing `Event.ENTER_FRAME` less often, and that you cannot use a `Timer` interval less than 500 milliseconds.

**Test #2**

But what happens when you try to update the screen?

**I made the app draw rows of circles in the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` handler. The screen updates are occurring as expected although just more slowly when the Flash app's browser tab is in the background.**

**Test #3**

But what about Flex? Flex components have their own life cycle, and the above drawing code doesn't participate in that life cycle. Let's add an event handler for `FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE`. This is an event that gets dispatched at the end of every Flex component life cycle (one iteration of committing any changed properties, measurement, and rendering). In this test, the event is not dispatched unless you do something like resizing the browser window (which causes Flex to redraw the screen).

**If the Flash app's browser tab is in the "background", `FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE` is not dispatched (when resizing the browser window).** Flash Player knows the app is not visible, and so it doesn't waste CPU trying to redraw the screen when I resize browser.

**Test #4**

Ok, now I think we're ready to try and do something close to what you're doing in your app... animate the position of something. In this case I'm going to move a `<s:Rect />` by changing it's x/y coordinates in the "enterFrame" handler.

**The screen still seems to be updating, albeit much slower when the Flash app's browser tab is in the "background".** Also note, that while the rectangle is moving, that `FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE` is also dispatched.

**Conclusion**

Based on the evidence above, Flash Player is **not** pausing the application, but rather it is **throttling the application** when the Flash knows the app is not visible.

Now what does this mean for your code? I'm not sure yet :) Perhaps your updates are occurring, but it's just so slow that it seems like nothing has changed?

CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:local="*"
               width="100%" height="100%"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.utils.getTimer;

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var timer:Timer;
            private var previousTimerTime: int = 0;
            private var timerEventDelta:int = 0;
            private var previousFrameTime:int = 0;
            private var enterFrameDelta:int = 0;
            private var surface:Graphics;
            private var drawingPoint:Point = new Point(0,0);

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                timer = new Timer(1000);
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerEvent);
                surface = drawingSurface.graphics;
            }

            private function toggleTimer():void
            {
                if (timer && timer.running)
                {
                    timer.reset();
                }
                else
                {
                    var interval:int = parseInt(timerInterval.text) as int;
                    timer.delay = interval;
                    timer.start();
                }
            }

            protected function onTimerEvent(event:TimerEvent):void
            {
                var currentTime:int = getTimer(); // milliseconds since the app started
                if (previousTimerTime == 0)
                {
                    trace("timer event (first event)");
                }
                else
                {
                    timerEventDelta = currentTime - previousTimerTime;
                    trace("timer event: time between last event: " + timerEventDelta);
                }
                previousTimerTime = currentTime;
            }

            protected function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
            {
                var currentTime:int = getTimer(); // milliseconds since the app started
                if (previousFrameTime == 0)
                {
                    trace("enter frame (first event)");
                }
                else
                {
                    enterFrameDelta = currentTime - previousFrameTime;
                    trace("enter frame: time between last event: " + enterFrameDelta);
                }
                previousFrameTime = currentTime;
                if (drawOnEachFrame.selected)
                    draw();
                if (moveOnEachFrame.selected)
                    moveRect();

            }

            protected function onUpdateComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                trace("update complete");
            }

            private function toggleEnterFrameHandler():void
            {
                if (hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME))
                {
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
                    previousFrameTime = 0;
                }
                else
                    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

            }

            private function toggleUpdateCompleteHandler():void
            {
                if (drawingSurface.hasEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE))
                {
                    drawingSurface.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, onUpdateComplete);

                }
                else
                    drawingSurface.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, onUpdateComplete);
            }

            private function draw():void
            {
                surface.beginFill(0xFF0000);
                surface.drawCircle(drawingPoint.x, drawingPoint.y, 5);
                surface.endFill();
                drawingPoint.x += 10;
                if (drawingPoint.x > drawingSurface.width)
                {
                    drawingPoint.x = 0;
                    drawingPoint.y += 15;
                }
            }

            private function moveRect():void
            {
                rectbert.x += 10;
                if (rectbert.x > drawingSurface.width - 50)
                {
                    rectbert.x = 0;
                    rectbert.y += 25;
                }
            }



        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button label="start/stop timer" click="toggleTimer()" />
        <s:Label text="Timer Interval (milliseconds)" />
        <s:TextInput id="timerInterval" text="1000" />
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button label="add/remove Event.ENTER_FRAME handler" click="toggleEnterFrameHandler()"/>
        <s:CheckBox id="drawOnEachFrame" label="Draw on each frame" />
        <s:CheckBox id="moveOnEachFrame" label="Move rectangle on each frame" />
        <s:Label text="(note this code doesn't move an draw at the same time)"/>
    </s:HGroup>

    <s:Button label="add/remove FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE hanlder " click="toggleUpdateCompleteHandler()"/>

    <s:Group id="drawingSurface" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Rect id="rectbert" width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#0000FF"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```